# Inclusion–exclusion principle on multiple set maximum value?

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

Say there are $46$ people in a club, $35$ of them are Chess lovers, $30$ of them are sports lovers, $40$ of them are Opera lovers, $38$ of them are video game lovers. So at least how many people are lovers for all $4$ activities?

---

I see there is a formula for questions like this. If the set size is $m$, with set $A, B, C, D...$ of size $a, b, c, d...$, Then:

minimum number for $A\cap B  = a + b -m$

minimum number for $A\cap B \cap C = a + b + c- 2m$

minimum number for $A\cap B \cap C \cap D = a + b + c + d- 3m$

and so on.

---

So why is this? How can I understand this formula?

Comment: $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|$.  Rearranging we have $|A\cap B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cup B|$.  Now, $|A|$ is obviously $a$, $|B|$ is $b$ and $|A\cup B|$ could not be higher than $m$, giving $|A\cap B|\geq a+b-m$.  Of course, $|A\cap B|$ should also be at least $0$ as well, so the more correct statement is $|A\cap B|\geq \min\{a+b-m,0\}$.  The others follow similarly.

Comment: @JMoravitz $A \cap B $ is easy, how to come up with $A \cap B \cap C$?